# How to upload a file to a server then record it in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Today I am trying to create an uploading ability where people can upload a photo that is a certain dimension (468px by 60px) to a directory on my server, for example, example.com/banners. Then, the URL of that banner would be sent to a MySQL database, for example example.com/banners/1.jpg. Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Google, google, google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploaded file are not in the $_POST but in $_FILES which in an array.

There is a sample to simply upload a file and retreive information on it.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

move_uploaded_file php directive is the way to move the temporary uploaded file to the final directory and there are many code to put the name in MySQL.

I let you search ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. To upload a file, you should create a `POST form` in HTML, using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
2. I would use PHP to get the file through `$_POST` and save it to the folder, while saving the path into a string (the **relative** path to your public folder, visible from the web browser).
3. After putting the file in the correct folder, generate a MySQL connection and save that path to the database.
4. When loading a page that needs that file, get the path string from the database and print it where it corresponds (usually inside an `img` tag).

Doesn't sound that hard to me, it's the basics. Did you already learn some PHP or similar language? HTML is **a must** for achieving this.

Comment: You should also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 0):

To save a file to the database using PHP you will need to upload the file using a form with enctype="multipart/form-data" as this:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you need to get the file binary content, name, type and size like this:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
```

Save the this fields in the database, the $fileContent needs to be saved in a field of the type Blob.

To create a download page for the file use php header function to change the HTML headers to the ones of your file and write the content of the Blob